# How to optimize my algorithm in OpenCV in Android?

Tags: android, image, opencv

I am trying to do a image process operation by using OpenCV (Android). I want to merge two images into a image, like this:

Image A and Image B are same size, and the result image is taking each column of A & B alternately. Result image is same size as A & B too.

[image]

Below is my code, it works.

```
            double[] dTempPixel;
            for(int iRow = 0 ; iRow < imgMat1.height() ; iRow++  ){
                for(int iCol = 0 ; iCol < imgMat1.width() ; iCol++ ){

                    if(iCol%2 != 0){
                        dTempPixel = imgMat2.get(iRow, iCol);
                    }else{
                        dTempPixel = imgMat1.get(iRow, iCol);
                    }
                    imgMat1.put(iRow, iCol,dTempPixel);
                }
            }
```

But the problem is, the speed is too slow if my image size is big. Do you know any methods that can improve the speed for doing this operation?

Comment: [PS : I wish the operation can be done within a second. I am thinking by applying mask operation will help, but I am not familiar with OpenCV ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a mask image of alternate cols with 0 and 1. Let's call it M. Multiply image A with M, B with 1-M and add them together.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice, do you mind to show me a sample code ?

Answer (score -1):

I have never done this in Android, but you could run multiple threads that would execute parts of your data.

Let's say you run as much threads as you have rows, then each thread would execute inner for loop simultaneously. Result should be faster then running algorithm serial.

I believe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_algorithm) and [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/9095/parallel-computing-in-opencv-244/) could help you get desired result.